# Calling a Matlab DLL function from C# via P/Invoke does not give expected output

Tags: c#, matlab, pinvoke, unmanaged, native-code

I wrote a simple matlab function that concatenates two strings:

```
function [z] = testCat(x,y)
z=strcat(x,y);
end
```

I used the following command to create a DLL out of it: `mcc -B csharedlib:libtestCat testCat`

This is what the signature of the function looks like in libtestCat.h:

```
extern LIB_libtestCat_C_API bool MW_CALL_CONV mlfTestCat(int nargout, mxArray** z, mxArray* x, mxArray* y);
```

Next, I created a C# Azure Project (MVC+Web API), and included the DLL cretaed above. I imported and called it as below:

```
        [DllImport(@"libtestCatNew.dll")]
                private static extern void libtestCatNewInitialize();
        [DllImport(@"libtestCatNew.dll")]
                private static extern void libtestCatNewTerminate();
        [DllImport(@"libtestCatNew.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, EntryPoint = "mlfTestCat", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        private static extern bool testCat([In]Int32 num, ref IntPtr output, [In]IntPtr input1, [In]IntPtr input2);

        [DllImport(@"libmx.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr mxCreateDoubleScalar([In]double value);

        [DllImport(@"libmx.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr mxCreateString([In]Char[] str);

        [DllImport(@"libmx.dll")]
        public static extern int mxGetString(IntPtr array_ptr, StringBuilder buf, int buflen);

                string context = "hi";
                string query = "how are you";

                bool ret = mclInitializeApplication_proxy("NULL", 0);
                  libtestCatNewInitialize();

                IntPtr contextIP1 = mxCreateString(contextCA);
                ViewBag.FinalText += " ContextIP1:";
                StringBuilder contextSB1 = new StringBuilder(200);
                mxGetString(contextIP1, contextSB1, 200);
                ViewBag.FinalText += contextSB1;
                IntPtr queryIP1 = mxCreateString(queryCA);
                ViewBag.FinalText += " QueryIP1:";
                StringBuilder querySB1 = new StringBuilder(200);
                mxGetString(queryIP1, querySB1, 200);
                ViewBag.FinalText += querySB1;
                IntPtr responseIP1 = mxCreateString(responseCA);
                bool ret2 = testCat(1, ref responseIP1, contextIP1, queryIP1);
                ViewBag.FinalText += " responseIP1:";
                StringBuilder responseSB1 = new StringBuilder(200);
                mxGetString(responseIP1, responseSB1, 200);
                ViewBag.FinalText += responseSB1;
```

However, the responseSB1 still remains the same. Here is how the final string looks like:

```
ViewBag.FinalText = ContextIP1:hi QueryIP1:how are you responseIP1:dummy response
```

The function works absolutely fine when executed from Matlab. I think I am doing some error while calling the function. Can someone help me understand where am I going wrong?